# Single machine & KVM-only Eucalyptus installation?

Tags: xen, kvm-virtualization, eucalyptus

I was wondering if there's an easy way to install Eucalyptus on a single VT-enabled machine (all Front End, CC, NC..), without installing XEN along with it's specific kernel and dependencies:

kernel-xen                        x86_64             2.6.18-194.3.1.el5                             update              20 M
 xen                               x86_64             3.0.3-105.el5_5.3                              update             1.9 M
 xen-libs                          x86_64             3.0.3-105.el5_5.3                              update             155 k

Only KVM. Is it possible ? Do I have to go for sources instead of packages ?

Answer (score 1):

you need at least two computers to get started. One will be the cloud 'servers' (CLC, WC, CC and SC) the other will be the cloud 'node' (NC). The node computer must have hardware-virtualization enabled CPUs.

This document really helped me getting my first cloud of the ground: http://cssoss.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/pdf-version-of-eucalyptus-beginners-guide-uec-edition/

Comment: You can use one computer as both the CC/CLC and as an NC. If you really really want.

Comment: @mattdm, you’re right it’s doable.  What I like with the two machines setup is the fact that it’s simple and that it prevents the simple fake of ‘just-starting-a-VM-by-hand-without-using-the-cloud’

Answer (score 1):

KVM only works fine !

I have tested it on UEC 10.10 (out of the box) and also on CentOS 5.5.
On CentOS you will need to uptdate your machine before installing KVM (yum update -y)
I am maintaining many nodes on CentOS with only kvm.

You dont have to install eucalyptus from source, the binary packages (tarbal or rpm) are both working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running centos or redhat?
Eucalyptus support only xen on those machines.
And kvm with standard rh/centos kernel is a bit too old.

Comment: I'm running Centos 5.5, and yes, the kernel is a bit too old but KVM works nicely on another Centos machine.

Comment: FWIW, CentOS 5.5 included a major update to KVM, invalidating this earlier answer.